# How to get a map view in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

[image]

How can I get this kind of map view in my application?

Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an MKMapView. For the popup, you'll need an annotation. Looking at the MKMapView documentation should get you pretty far..

Answer (score 0):

You should be using MKMapView - as donkim mentioned do some reading on MKMapView, taht would get you pretty far. You can use MKAnnotations for the maps annotations. You can google for "custom annotations" if you want to want to use custom images for annotations.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710049/can-someone-point-me-to-a-leak-in-this-code) post that i posted a while ago for a memory leak, but it pretty much has the code to show annotations on the map. I have borrowed the code from internet too...

Answer (score 0):

I guess I need to call this... in

```
//NSString *latlong = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", 52.366428f,4.896349f] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//........for destination location.

//NSString *dlatlong = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//for the current location. this. where coordinate is CLLocationManager2D.

//NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%@&saddr=%@&daddr=%@",

//latlong, latlong, dlatlong];
```

need not to use mkmapkit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easier way of show a location on the map, however this approach will not implement a map view inside your application but it will open the map application.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Oslo"];
```

After the q- parameter key you can write the same string as you normally write in google maps specifying the address. Read the documentation for UIApplication class for more information on this. Note, this will also automatically make a annotation for the location.

Just mention this because others may find this a useful  if they don't need the map inside the application.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Here is a list of other parameters:

http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters