# Can someone point me to a leak in this code?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

DisplayMap.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>


@interface DisplayMap : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
    NSString *title; 
    NSString *subtitle;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

DisplayMap.m

```
#import "DisplayMap.h"


@implementation DisplayMap

@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;


-(void)dealloc{
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I am implementing the above in a map view to show annotations. On the viewdidload, i run through a set of coordinates and display them on the map using the above mentioned annotation class.

```
for(int i=0;i<[xmlParameter count];i++){
    region.center.latitude=(double)[[[xmlParameter objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    region.center.longitude =(double) [[[xmlParameter objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:4] doubleValue] ;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.08f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.08f;
    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
    ann.title = [[xmlParameter objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0];
    ann.subtitle = [[xmlParameter objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1]; 
    ann.coordinate = region.center; 
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    if(i==zoomtoParameter){
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];            
        //showAnnotation=ann;       
        [mapView selectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:YES];          
        //[mapView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
    }

    [ann release];
}
```

Running with instruments with leaks, says there is a DisplayMap leak for 32Bytes in the viewDidLoad method. I can't figure out how; i am releasing the DisplayMap object right after am done with it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: try releasing `subtitle` too in your `dealloc`.

Comment: you released  your title, but where did you allocate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `subtitle` property is declared with a `copy` attribute, which means you are responsible for releasing it. The following change to your `dealloc` method should do the trick:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [subtitle release];
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

***Edit:*** To elaborate: Cocoa's [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) rules state that you must `release` any memory that you `alloc`, `retain` or `copy`. In the case of synthesized properties, this means that you must include the appropriate `release` messages in your `-dealloc` method. See my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189919/how-is-release-handled-for-synthesized-retain-properties) on this topic for more details.

In the sample code that you provided, the following line:

```
ann.subtitle = [[xmlParameter objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1];
```

Creates a copy of the indicated object. When you later call `[ann release]`, that copied object will be leaked unless you explicitly release it.

Comment: Isn't `[ ann release ];` responsible for deallocating all its member variables ?

Comment: eJames is right. I thing you get a warning when you miss [super dealloc ]; . When you get a warning, solve it:)

Comment: @Mahesh: The `-dealloc` method is responsible for releasing any member variables that were allocated, retained or copied (and not yet released) at any point in the lifetime of that object.

Comment: @Mahesh: to clarify: In your example `[ann release]` *will* release the memory for the `ann` object, but `ann` contains a pointer (subtitle) to a `NSString` object. The memory for the *pointer* will be released, but the memory for the `NSString` object that it points to will not.

Comment: Thanks ejames, that did the trick. Was banging my head over this one. I thought [ann release] will take care of the title and subtitle. Not only did it solve the problem but i definitely did learn something. Thanks once again

Comment: @Veeru: glad to be of service `:)`