# How to add hyperlink in subtitle on callout view using objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iPhone app, I require to show the hyperlink to a website in subtitle on callout view.
I am using displaymap class url is [Can someone point me to a leak in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710049/can-someone-point-me-to-a-leak-in-this-code)

I need add hyperlink in subtitle.help me

By
Siva M

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fulfill your requirement in this way..

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *locationView;

    locationView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"] autorelease];

    locationView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    locationView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    locationView.canShowCallout =YES;
    locationView.annotation=annotation;
    locationView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    UITextView *text=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    text.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeLink ;
    text.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    text.editable=NO;
    text.text=@"http://google.com";
    locationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = text;
    return locationView;
}
```

Comment: Yes,My requirement in this way but we are already using rightCalloutAccessoryView and leftCalloutAccessoryView to add image, i need add hyperlink in subtitle

Comment: you can set a UIView as rightCalloutAccessoryView or leftCalloutAccessoryView. in that UIView You can add image and TextView both.

Comment: if it possible to add hyperlink in subtitle ?